# Countif rows are within 1,000 milliseconds or 1 second

Tags: excel, time, intervals, milliseconds, seconds

I am capturing data. Some data comes in 3x/1ms (.001sec) some comes in 2x/1sec ( 1,000ms). Here is a sample of the logged data. Have 50k rows. Want to know how many times out of the 50k rows do I log 3x/1ms. The data comes in random. The red box shows data coming in 3x/1ms the blue box shows 2x per interval of second.
[image]

```
11:37:40.680 AM
11:37:41.140 AM
11:37:41.450 AM
11:37:41.950 AM
11:37:42.400 AM
11:37:42.700 AM
11:37:43.180 AM
11:37:43.510 AM
11:37:44.470 AM
11:37:44.780 AM
11:37:45.260 AM
11:37:45.730 AM
11:37:46.190 AM
11:37:46.660 AM
11:37:47.130 AM
11:37:47.450 AM
11:37:47.920 AM
11:37:48.390 AM
11:37:48.870 AM
```

Comment: Is the data text, or date formatted as text? Is the data for example 9am formatted as 9:00:00.000 AM or 09:00:00.000 AM (with a leading 0)?

Comment: When I check isnumber it is True. It is date formatted but not text. I’m using now() but formatted w/ time

Comment: `[$-en-US]h:mm:ss.000 AM/PM;@` formatted cells

Comment: *Want to know how many times out of the 50k rows do I log 3x/1ms* Could you add example of expected output? Not sure i you are expecting a single value or multiple values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 2019 formulas:

I think you also can't use `LET` or spill formulas so I think you would have to use a helper column to identify which timestamps meet your criteria, then add up the helper column.

The helper column formula to flag each timestamp `TRUE` or `FALSE`, starting in `A2`:

```
=AND(FLOOR.MATH(A1,1/24/60/60)<>FLOOR.MATH(A2,1/24/60/60),COUNTIFS(A2:$A$22,">="&FLOOR.MATH(A2,1/24/60/60),A2:$A$22,"<"&(FLOOR.MATH(A2,1/24/60/60)+(1/24/60/60)))>=3)
```

`FLOOR.MATH, 1/24/60/60` to get the milliseconds

`COUNTIFS` to count how many timestamps are above the current millisecond and below the next millisecond

Another `FLOOR.MATH, 1/24/60/60` to check whether the previous timestamp is in the same millisecond as the current timestamp, so that you only count each millisecond group once

Then `=COUNTIF(B2:B22,TRUE)` on the helper column to count how many timestamps were flagged as `TRUE` matching your criteria.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems `ROUND` does not work with milliseconds but `FLOOR.MATH` does

`LET` to define the range you want to look at

`FLOOR.MATH, 1/24/60/60` to get the milliseconds

`COUNTIFS` to count how many timestamps are above the current millisecond and below the next millisecond

`IF` to return the timestamp if there are 3 or more matches

`COUNT` and `UNIQUE` to count how many timestamps meet the "3 or more matches" criteria

Subtract 1 because `UNIQUE` also includes the 0 for the timestamps that do not meet the criteria.

```
=LET(RNG,A2:A21,MS,FLOOR.MATH(RNG,1/24/60/60),
COUNT(UNIQUE(IF(COUNTIFS(RNG,">="&MS,RNG,"<"&(MS+(1/24/60/60)))>=3,MS,0)))-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Anyway to not do it w/ out the unique function? I only have excel 2019 not 365 or 2021.